# How can I remove values and add an index column to a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

I have this data coming in:

```
[]
0:{time: 1525355921817, sym: "AAPL", price: 169.16, size: 98, stop: false, …}
1:{time: 1525355923216, sym: "AAPL", price: 170.15, size: 6, stop: false, …}
2:{time: 1525355923216, sym: "AAPL", price: 170.06, size: 57, stop: false, …}
```

I need to get it into the following format:

```
0:{"time": 1525355921817, "sym": "AAPL", "price": 169.16, "index": 0} 
1:{"time": 1525355923216, "sym": "AAPL", "price": 170.15, "index": 1} 
2:{"time": 1525355923216, "sym": "AAPL", "price": 170.06, "index": 2}
```

Basically just dropping the size and stop and adding an index column. I also need to be able to access it as `this.data.price` and get back all the price values... is this even possible? This data comes from a service in angular

How can I achieve this? (please be aware that I am not an experienced user of angular or javascript)

Comment: Generally you shouldn't need an index column in the objects. That is always easy to get using `Array#indexOf()` when you actually need it or accessing the index of `ngFor`. How would it actually be used in the angular app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `map` the array of objects. You can deconstruct each object for shorter code.

```js
let arr = [{time: 1525355921817, sym: "AAPL", price: 169.16, size: 98, stop: false,},{time: 1525355923216, sym: "AAPL", price: 170.15, size: 6, stop: false,},{time: 1525355923216, sym: "AAPL", price: 170.06, size: 57, stop: false,}];

let result = arr.map(({size,stop,...r}, i) => Object.assign(r, {index: i}));

console.log( result );
```

Doc: [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.map()` to create the desired ouput:

```js
let data = [{time: 1525355921817, sym: "AAPL", price: 169.16, size: 98, stop: false},{time: 1525355923216, sym: "AAPL", price: 170.15, size: 6, stop: false},{time: 1525355923216, sym: "AAPL", price: 170.06, size: 57, stop: false}];

let result = data.map((o, i) => ({
  time: o.time,
  sym: o.sym,
  price: o.price,
  index: i
}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I also need to be able to access it as this.data.price and get back all the price values... is this even possible?

Assuming the array is under `data`:

```
 const groupValue = (arr, key) => arr[key] = arr.map(el => el[key]);

 groupValue(this.data, "price");

 console.log(this.data.price);
```